# Guess the Word Game: Guesses For Secret Word Aren't Being Accepted

Tags: python

I'm working in Python 3.x and am fairly new, so I hope what I am asking makes sense. I am supposed to be focusing on for loops and strings for this word-guessing game.
Here's the (jumbled/lengthy/cluttered) code I have so far:

```
import sys
import random

def Main():
    PlayAgain = "y"
    print("COP 1000 Project 4 - Courtney Kasonic - Guess the Word Game")
    print("I'm thinking of a word; can you guess what it is?")
    while PlayAgain == "y":
        Words = "apple alphabet boomarang cat catharsis define decide elephant fish goat horizon igloo jackelope ketchup loop limousine monkey night octopus potato quick rebel separate test underway violin world yellow zebra".split()
        SecretWord = random.choice(Words)
        MissedLetters = ""
        CorrectLetters = ""
        ChosenWord = GetWord(Words)
        Guess = FiveLetters(CorrectLetters+MissedLetters)
        for Guess in ChosenWord:
            CorrectLetters = CorrectLetters + Guess
        ShowWord(CorrectLetters, ChosenWord)
        for i in ChosenWord:
            CLetters = ""
            if Guess in ChosenWord:
                Blanks = "_" * len(SecretWord)
                for i in range(len(SecretWord)):
                    if SecretWord[i] in CLetters:
                        Blanks = Blanks[i] + SecretWord[i]
                        print(Blanks)
                        print(CLetters)

def GetWord(List):
    SecretWord = random.choice(List)
    return(SecretWord)

**def FiveLetters(LettersGuessed):
    a = 2
    if a > 1:
        print("Enter five letters to check: ",end="")
        Guess = input()
        if len(Guess) != 5:
            print("Please enter five letters.")
        elif Guess in LettersGuessed:
            print("You already guessed that letter.")
        elif Guess not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            print("Please enter a letter.")
        else:
            return(Guess)**

def ShowWord(CLetters, SecretWord):
    print("\nHere is the word showing the letters that you guessed:\n")
    CLetters = ""
    Blanks = "_" * len(SecretWord)
    for i in range(len(SecretWord)):
        if SecretWord[i] in CLetters:
            Blanks = Blanks[i] + SecretWord[i]
            print(Blanks)
            print(CLetters)
        return(Blanks, SecretWord, CLetters)

def CheckLetters(Letters):
    Letters = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z".split()
    for Letters in Word:
        print(Letters)
    return(Letters)

Main()
```

The bolded area is where I am having problems. Only five letters can be entered to "check" to see if they are in the secret word. It will only accept input like "abcde". It will not accept input like "aaaaa" or "muihi" i.e. it won't accept guesses that are not in order or have more than one of the same letter.

---

I am also having trouble with the underscores. Not sure if the code I have for it up there is correct or not. The letters that are guessed correctly will not replace the appropriate underscore.

Ex: Secret Word = dog. If I guess the letters "mopfe" (though I can't because of issue above) then it will print out "_ _ _" without the "o".

Comment: Please use lowercase for variable names and functions. Use capital letters for classes

Comment: yes, welcome to python, please go and read pep8: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Overlooking the lack of "style" your code haves, you probably need to debug your code yourself before coming here for other people to look for your errors. You should test each part of your application individually, looking for the component that isn't behaving as it should. Doing this, you probably gonna be able to solve the issue by yourself, and if not, then you would've isolated the issue and would be able to make a more **concise** question which more users will be willing to answer to.

Answer (score 1):

You will inevitably ask more questions, assuming you don't want to fail. If you ask those questions on StackOverflow you should probably [read the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). Since you are using python you should probably also read the style guide (i.e. PEP 8), it was mentioned in the comments. This code, while incomplete, will get you started.

```
import sys
import random

def main():
    play_again = "y"
    print("COP 1000 Project 4 - Courtney Kasonic - Guess the Word Game")
    print("I'm thinking of a word; can you guess what it is?")

    words = "apple alphabet boomarang cat catharsis define decide elephant fish goat horizon igloo jackelope ketchup loop limousine monkey night octopus potato quick rebel separate test underway violin world yellow zebra".split()
    secret_word = random.choice(words)
    correct_letters = ""

    while play_again == "y":

        guess = five_letters(correct_letters)

        for letter in guess:
            if letter in secret_word:
                correct_letters += letter

        show_word(correct_letters, secret_word)

def five_letters(letters_guessed):

        guess = raw_input("Enter five letters to check: ")

        if len(guess) != 5:
            print("Please enter five letters.")
        elif guess in letters_guessed:
            print("You already guessed that letter.")
        elif guess not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            print("Please enter a letter.")
        else:
            return guess

def show_word(correct_letters, secret_word):
    print("\nHere is the word showing the letters that you guessed:\n")
    word_display = ""

    for index, letter in enumerate(secret_word):
        if letter in correct_letters:
            word_display += letter
        else:
            word_display += "_"

    print word_display

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```